# I created a downloadable mp3 file in php, but after downloading its not playing

Tags: php

The file is getting downloaded,but it's empty.
here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $file=$_POST['file_name'];
   if($file){

      header("Content-type:audio/mp3");
      header("Content-disposition:attachment; filename='$file' ");
      readfile('files/'.$file);
      exit();
    }
}
?>

<html>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="lat lag gayi">
    lat lag gayi <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="download">
</form>
</html>
```

what's wrong?
please help.

Comment: that's all you can tell us? "not playing"? what a thorough investigation.

Comment: Because `./files/lat lag gayi` probably doesn't exist. So you're downloading a zero byte file. `if ($file)` doesn't check if the file exists, you need to use `if (file_exists($file))`.

Comment: Did you check the crc32 value?

Comment: yea..u right. i used the file_exists() to check....but it's returning false even if the file is there...so what should i do now?

Comment: @JuhiDavda - did you check my answer below about Content-type?

Answer (score 0):

`Content-type:audio/mp3`

You can try changing this to `Content-type: audio/mpeg`

Also try helping the browser by giving filename='$file.mp3' with an extension.

[Audio media types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)